# I keep getting this error message, while trying to make a detail page for a table

Tags: php, html, mysql

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '' (T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE),
>   expecting identifier (T_STRING) or variable (T_VARIABLE) or number
>   (T_NUM_STRING) in /var/www/2909kher/entabell/detaljer.php on line 23

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<body>
Dette er detaljer.php <br>
<?php

include('oppkobling.php');

//$by = $_POST[''];
//echo($by);

// Lag SQL-setning
$query = 'SELECT * FROM rikestemennesker where id = '.$_GET['Plass'];

// Kjør spørringen
$resultat = mysqli_query($db, $query);

// Lagre antall poster som er funnet
$antall = mysqli_num_rows($resultat);

$rad = mysqli_fetch_array($resultat);

echo "Navn: ".$rad['Navn']."<img src='./bilder/'.$rad['Bilde'].<br>";
echo "Land: ".$rad['Land']."<br>";
echo "Nettoformue: ".$rad['Nettoformue']."<br>";
echo "Kilde: ".$rad['Kilde']."<br>";


?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `$query = 'SELECT * FROM rikestemennesker where id = '.$_GET['Plass'];` I hope this never goes in production.

Comment: it is the `'` in the query causing your error btw

Comment: @NappingRabbit there's nothing wrong with the query. The error is shown in the answer below.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please do not vandalize your posts.  By posting on the Stack Exchange network, you've granted a non-revocable right for SE to distribute that content (under the [CC BY-SA 3.0 license](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/)). By SE policy, any vandalism will be reverted.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in

```
echo "Navn: ".$rad['Navn']."<img src='./bilder/'.$rad['Bilde'].<br>";
```

You forgot an " and used a ' instead of "

```
echo "Navn: ".$rad['Navn']."<img src='./bilder/".$rad['Bilde']."' /><br>";
```

**Edit**

For better readability, use single quotes when echoing HTML.

```
echo 'Navn: ' . $rad['Navn'] . '<img src="./bilder/' . $rad['Bilde'] . '" /><br>';
```

Comment: while `echo "Navn: ".$rad['Navn']."<img src='./bilder/'.$rad['Bilde'].<br>";` may not be what they intended to do, it's still valid syntax, so I doubt that's the issue.

Comment: "For better readability" - Well, no. Simple PHP2-style array interpolation syntax would arguably be more readable than endless concatenations.

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca Yes it is. The $rad['Bilde'] will be executed within double quotes.

Comment: @mario, He is not using this PHP2-style syntax, so I just gave a tip.